# What are the different meanings of "Hatchet job"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I recently used the term "Hatchet job" to refer to a shabby but ad-hoc solution. When I tried to find out if I used it in the right sense, there was only one website among many which connoted this meaning. Every other website spoke about harsh review or a violent prose.

Was I right in using the term in the sense that I did?

Comment: Hello, Bharg. Dictionaries research usages, and are thus far less likely to mislead people about acceptability than are single examples on the internet. What do you find dictionaries have to say on this? // I trust you'll find the answer to be 'No; this usage is (or **very** probably is) non-standard'; you're perhaps confusing 'hatchet job' with how the verb 'butcher' is used metaphorically.

Answer (score 1):

Officially-speaking, no - your usage is not supported by written convention. The strict meaning of "hatchet job" is given as

> a maliciously destructive critique or act

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hatchet-job?s=t)

> a forceful or malicious verbal attack

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hatchet%20job)

The usual (British) English phrase for what you are describing is a "lash-up":

> something hastily put together or improvised

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lash%20up)

Although there are many alternatives ("Jerry-built", "jury-rigged" and so on).

Comment: If I'd seen this question earlier, I'd have posted exactly what Spratty did, for which I have no citation except personal experience going back at least 50 years…

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the nasty review meaning, which I had never heard of until now, there are at least two others in common usage.

The first refers to an actual, not metaphorical hatchet, and relates to poor craftmanship, laziness, or ineptitude. A hatchet is a hewing tool, as opposed to a crafting tool such as an adz. If you had half-a-dozen axe-like tools, the hatchet is probably the most abused (and cheapest) tool in the shed. You saved the felling axe and facing axe and splitting axe for their rightful jobs. The hatchet was often used for demolition. So a *hatchet job* is when opinions vary as to whether you made something, or just destroyed a perfectly good piece of stock in the attempt.

https://books.google.com/books?id=GosGOVZPwX8C&lpg=PA17&ots=IBwOatxauw&dq=%22hatchet%20job%22%20vindictive%20response&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q=%22hatchet%20job%22%20vindictive%20response&f=false

from "The King of the Stars".

The second is a malicious act of budget cutting, normally used when referring to cases where the budget is cut, eliminated, or the threat is made to do so, in order to prevent a particular enforcement action. However, it has recently been used to imply recklessnes, as opposed to vindictiveness, such as here -

> The Maryland Democrat said that even if Trump's proposal were just a starting point in a negotiation, it needs to be rational. "It was simply a hatchet job to increase very substantially the defense side of the budget without paying for it except with these irrational cuts," he [Rep Hoyer] argued.

http://www.cnbc.com/2017/03/16/no-2-house-democrat-says-trumps-budget-blueprint-is-a-hatchet-job-thats-doa.html

Hoyer's usage seems to be conflating both usages - that it is an unjust budget cut, and that it was done in a slipshod manner.

in a similar vein -

> GOP Hatchet Job On State Budget Will Hurt Montanans
>
> HELENA -- The Montana Republican Party's proposal to cut more money
>   from the state's budget is completely unnecessary and reckless. [...]

http://www.publicnow.com/view/FE98553D25B37008E6B67D76B9AF266230848A84?2017-01-12-00:30:34+00:00-xxx6814

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you used the term correctly. The top rated definition on Urban Dictionary for ["hatchet job"](http://hatchet-job.urbanup.com/5106921) says,

> Performing an action in a very rough, imprecise, and uncraftsman like fashion. The end result of the action is a completed task that is of very poor quality.

Although not an authoritative source and it may make some here cringe, I have found Urban Dictionary to be quite illuminating when trying to understand colloquialisms, idioms, and slang usage. USUALLY, the top rated answer is spot-on. But I wouldn't rely on it as a scholarly source or anything "official", similar to how Wikipedia is.

Also, I know and use this term myself as a native English (USA) speaker of 46 years.

Comment: How many other dictionaries did you check in? Note that OP does not add a 'slang' (etc) (or AmE) tag.

Comment: As one hacks with a hatchet and a hack can be a rough and ready solution this isn't implausible, as accepted use or an error. It should be possible to find a better source if this is widely known slang.